# несколько условий if

Tags: python, python-3.x, if

Всем привет! есть конструкция типа:

```
if a in b:
    print(a)
elif a in c:
    print(a)
elif a in d:
    print(a)
else:
    pass
```

как сделать так, чтобы переменная а печаталась только при выполнении ВСЕХ if-условий, а если хоть одно не выполнялось-то pass? на ум приходят только костыли, а хотелось лаконичного решения

Comment: Используйте составное условие с and

Comment: у вас код противоречит тексту. Код печатает, если любое из условий истинно.

Comment: @jfs да это так, а хотелось бы проверить, какие из переменных b,c,d определены, и их уже проверить при помощи and как посоветовал Сергей

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если необходимо выполнение **всех** условий:

```
if (a in b and a in c and a in d):
    print(a)
else:
    pass
```

Если необходимо выполнение **хотя бы одного** условия:

```
if (a in b or a in c or a in d):
    print(a)
else:
    pass
```

Comment: понял, а если переменные b,c,d не всегда определены, а например сейчас только b,c , а через пару циклов определены с,d? нужно сделать проверку только с определенными переменными

Comment: Не уверен, но думаю что это будет работать. Питон особо не знаю, но в некоторых других языках `a and b and c` работает так: проверяется `a`, и если там `false`, то `b` и `c` даже не проверяются.

Comment: это немного не то, надо так: проверить какие переменные определены, и их проверить уже при помощи and.

Comment: @jfs сейчас сделаю

Answer (score 5):

Чтобы проверить, содержится ли элемент во *всех* доступных коллекциях:

```
if all(item in it for it in collections):
    print(item)
```

где к примеру: `collections = b, c, d`.

Чтобы проверить содержится ли элемент в *любой* из коллекций:

```
if any(item in it for it in collections):
    print(item)
```